# Arbitrary dimensional object with constant ratio of volume to containing hyper cube's volume?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let me introduce what I need by giving an example which is not working:

n-sphere with radius 1 and respective hypercube with edges of length 2.
The ratio reaches already in 10th dimension a level of less than 1%.

**My question essentially is whether a geometric object G with following features exists**:

1. The hyper-cube containing G is canonically defined for all dimensions with edges of length L and center is the 0.
2. G is contained in above hyper-cube for all dimensions.
3. The ratio of the G's volume and the hyper-cubes volume is constant over all dimensions.
4. Calculating whether a point chosen from the hyper-cube uniformly at random is contained in G is canonical. (in other words: the calculation can be written down as a single formula depending on the number of dimensions and of course L and the point)
5. Any path along the surface of G is differentiable.
6. The volume ratio should be either adjustable or between .2 and .8.

(point 5 is maybe not correctly formulated. I want to make sure that G is not "edgy"/"weird" (sorry for these terms). Maybe it is the same as when I request G to be Riemann integrable)

---

I need such an object to generate a sample data set from an arbitrary dimensional space to benchmark performance of SVMs (and other ML algorithms) over dimensionality of input space.

Comment: Wow, interesting question!

Comment: I'd go along this: inflate a sphere inside a hypercube. At some point you'll obtain a figure that is flat and touching the cube inside the square surfaces, locally a "hyper"cylinder near edges and something like a "hyper"sphere near vertices. Then you'll need to adjust all parameters to obtain the desired volume and derivability.

Comment: What is the purpose of condition number 5?

Comment: @Zackkenyon: to assure the object is shaped "pleasently" :)

Comment: so like, a cube would qualify?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: you're welcome to put it into a formula. I get your idea, but I fear "adjust all parameters" dooms it non-canonical, plus I think it is quite unclear what those parameters actually are.

Comment: @Zackkenyon: a cube is not pleasent in this case because it is too simple - it likely won't suit the ultimate purpose. In that sense, (5) not just assures a pleasent shape but also prevents a too trival shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space defined by the solutions of the following inequality seems to do the trick (d being the dimensions of the space):

$$1-(\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_i^{2d})^{1/d} \geq \frac{1}{d}$$

The space for d=2 and d=3 looks "pleasant":

[image] [image]

The ratio of the solution space volume and the cube also seems to be quite consistent at 0.5:

[image]

```
library(rgl)

vol <- function(d) {    
    p <- function(x) 1 - sum(x^(2*d))^(1/d)
    g <- matrix(runif(d*100000, -1, 1), ncol=d)
    s <- apply(g, 1, p)
    v <- ifelse(s >= 1/d, 1, -1)

    if(d==2) plot(g[v==1,], xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1))
    if(d==3) plot3d(g[v==1,], xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), zlim=c(-1,1))

    sum(v == 1) / nrow(g)
}

ratios <- sapply(1:100,vol)

plot(ratios, xlab="dimension")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is the idea put forward by TZakrevskiy in his comment: Fix $n\geq2$,  let $C:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\>|\>\|x\|_\infty\leq1$ be the hypercube of side length $2$, and let $B$ be the unit ball in ${\mathbb R}^n$. For $0<\epsilon<1$ the Minkowski sum
$$G:=(1-\epsilon) C +\epsilon B$$
is a "rounded cube" with $C^1$-surface. There exists a famous formula for ${\rm vol}(G)$, but it is obvious that
$${{\rm vol}(G)\over {\rm vol}(C)}>(1-\epsilon)^n\ ,$$
which can be made $>1-\delta$ for any given $\delta>0$.

There can be no question of "any path along the surface of $G$ being differentiable", for any $G$ proposed whatsoever. However one can say the following: Since the $G$ above has a $C^1$-surface it makes sense to consider differentiable curves on $\partial G$.

PS: I don't understand why you didn't like Will Jagy's answer, so that it was subsequently deleted.

Comment: I don't know why Mr Jagy decided to delete his answer. My approach to the problem I try to solve behind the question is intuitive. Hence, and I am sorry for that, the answer has to get the idea of what I try to accomplish. And Mr Jagy's solution led to boxes taking up full axes within the cube. This solution might be the answer to the mathematical aspects I try my best to describe - but it doesn't serve the purpose of a useful sample space

Comment: Q1: Is it possible to decide (effort no more than O(n)) whether for a vector g in G (eps given) there are two vectors c in C and b in B such that g = (1 - eps) * c + eps * b? In other words: is it easy to decide whether g in deed lies within G? How is it done?

Comment: Q2: What is the formula to calculate the volume of G = (1-eps)  * C + eps * B?

Comment: @Яaffael $x\in G$ $\iff$ ($x\in (1-\epsilon)C$ or $dist (x,\partial (1-\epsilon)C)\le \epsilon$). The first term is calculated by at most $O(n)$, the second one can be made $O(n)$, too.